# LINQ Union two lists that have same ID but different types

Tags: c#, json, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am trying to merge two lists into one List without duplicates

JOIN operator returns only common elements

These are lists in JSON

List1 is:

```
{
    "screenID": 96,
    "create": true,
    "read": true,
    "update": true,
    "delete": true,
    "print": true
},
{
    "screenID": 97,
    "create": true,
    "read": true,
    "update": true,
    "delete": true,
    "print": true
},
{
    "screenID": 98,
    "create": true,
    "read": true,
    "update": true,
    "delete": true,
    "print": true
}
```

List2 is:

```
{
    "screenID": 96,
    "create": true,
    "read": true,
    "update": true,
    "delete": true,
    "print": false
},
{
    "screenID": 97,
    "create": true,
    "read": true,
    "update": true,
    "delete": true,
    "print": false
}
```

If ScreenID is same then I want to compare between CRUD elements like:

```
if(ScreenID == 96){
Create = List1.Create == true && List2.Create == false ? true : false
}
```

I tried this :
var finalList = list1.Union(list2);

but the result was:

```
{
    "screenID": 96,
    "create": true,
    "read": true,
    "update": true,
    "delete": true,
    "print": true
},
{
    "screenID": 97,
    "create": true,
    "read": true,
    "update": true,
    "delete": true,
    "print": true
},
{
    "screenID": 98,
    "create": true,
    "read": true,
    "update": true,
    "delete": true,
    "print": true
},
{
    "screenID": 96,
    "create": true,
    "read": true,
    "update": true,
    "delete": true,
    "print": false
},
{
    "screenID": 97,
    "create": true,
    "read": true,
    "update": true,
    "delete": true,
```

I am beginner in LINQ so any help is appreciated

**EDIT**
I am using .NET 3.1

Comment: What you posted aren't collections anyway, they look like parts of a JSON array. Post actual classes and actual code. You may be able to use [UnionBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.unionby?view=net-7.0), eg `.UnionBy(x=>x.ScreenId)`. This will return the first of the duplicates. You can control which that one is by first ordering the two collections by ScreenID, Create etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** I've made some changes to adapt my original answer to .Net 3.5, this should now work provided you're working with C# 7.3 or later (Set by `<LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>` in your .csproj file). I ditched the `HashSet<T>` for a `Dictionary<T>` which actually made the whole thing less verbose.

While the exising answer is good I'd like to add an alternate approach using an extension method that essentially should do the same as `UnionBy` but accept an additonal `Func<T, T, T>` for handling duplicates.

<s>The `UnionComparer` makes it a bit verbose but that essentially just wraps the `IEqualityComparer<TKey>` for the key selector.</s>

```cs
public static IEnumerable<T> UnionBy<T, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<T> first,
    IEnumerable<T> second,
    Func<T, TKey> keySelector,
    Func<T, T, T> duplicateHandler,
    IEqualityComparer<TKey> keyComparer = null)
{
    if(keyComparer is null)
        keyComparer = EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default;

    var result = new Dictionary<TKey, T>(keyComparer);

    foreach (var item in first)
        result.Add(keySelector(item), item);

    foreach (var item in second)
    {
        var key = keySelector(item);
        if (result.TryGetValue(key, out var duplicate))
        {
            result[key] = duplicateHandler(item, duplicate);
        }
        else
        {
            result.Add(key, item);
        }
    }
    return result.Values;
}
```

I've made a simple example class for your data:

```cs
class Operation
{
    public int ScreenId { get; set; }
    public bool Create { get; set; }
}
```

Usage:

```cs
var first = new List<Operation>()
{
    new Operation () { ScreenId = 1, Create = false },
    new Operation () { ScreenId = 2, Create = false },
    new Operation () { ScreenId = 3, Create = false },
};
            var second = new List<Operation>()
{
    new Operation () { ScreenId = 3, Create = true },
    new Operation () { ScreenId = 4, Create = true },
    new Operation () { ScreenId = 5, Create = true },
};

var result = first.UnionBy(
    second,
    o => o.ScreenId,
    (a, b) => new Operation { ScreenId = a.ScreenId, Create = a.Create || b.Create });

foreach (var operation in result)
    Console.WriteLine($"ID: {operation.ScreenId}, Create: {operation.Create}");

Console.ReadLine();
```

[image: Result]

<s>**EDIT:** I just saw you are limited to .Net 3.5, I'm not entirely sure you will not have to make any changes to this but `HashSet<T>` and `IEqualityComparer<T>` should be supported</s>

Comment: I tried it but it looks like that "UnionBy" is not supported I sot an error message says :"List<>' does not contain a definition for 'UnionBy' and no accessible extension method 'UnionBy' accepting a first argument of type "

Comment: It's probably a language version issue rather than a .Net issue but I had to make some other changes to make this work with .Net 3.5 anyway. Does this help in any way?

Comment: That's exactly what I needed!! Thank you a lot I have been trying it for 2 days!

Answer (score 0):

.NET 6 introduced [UnionBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.unionby?view=net-7.0) which can be used to combine two collections based on an expression. When duplicates are found, the method returns the first item it encounters. The two collections should be ordered first to control which item is returned :

```
var ordA=colA.OrderByDescending(x=>new {x.ScreenId,x.Create,x.Update,x.Delete});
var ordB=colB.OrderByDescending(x=>new {x.ScreenId,x.Create,x.Update,x.Delete});

var unioned=ordA.UnionBy(ordB,x=>x.ScreenId);
```

For more complex logic, the order expression should be modified to ensure the desired item comes first. For example, to select the item with the most flags, `Enumerable.Count(t=>t)` can be used :

```
var ordA=colA.OrderByDescending(x=>new {
    x.ScreenId,
    Count=new[]{ x.Create,x.Update,x.Delete }
              .Count(t=>t)
});
```

**Using DistinctBy**

In previous versions .NET versions the [MoreLINQ](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ) library can be used. There's no `UnionBy` but `DistinctBy` can be used for the same job after concatenation. Once again, the order controls what is returned :

```
var all=colA.Concat(colB);

var unioned=all.OrderByDescending(x=>new { x.ScreenId,x.Create,x.Update,x.Delete})
               .DistinctBy(x=>x.ScreenId);
```

[DistinctBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinctby?view=net-7.0) is also available in .NET 6.

Comment: I am Using .NET 3.5 so I don't think this is possible here right?

Comment: That went out of support a long time ago. You should specify information like that in the question. You *can* use these methods though, through the MoreLINQ library

Comment: Okay I will take a look on MoreLINQ library thank you

Comment: I added an example using MoreLINQ and DistinctBy

Answer (score 0):

With class

```
    public class Screen
    {
        public int screenID { get; set; }
        public bool create { get; set; }
        public bool read { get; set; }
        public bool update { get; set; }
        public bool delete { get; set; }
        public bool print { get; set; }
    }
```

This simple union works:

```
    var result = list.Union(list2)
        .GroupBy(x => x.screenID)
        .Select(x => new 
        {
            screenID = x.Key,
            create = x.Any(y => y.create),
            read = x.Any(y => y.read),
            update = x.Any(y => y.update),
            delete = x.Any(y => y.delete),
            print = x.Any(y => y.print)
        });
```